# 2 versions of each page

Tags: seo, jekyll, hosting, liquid

I have created my blog using Jekyll. I have been told my site is indexing 3 URL's to some pages, which would be classed as duplicated content to Google. I have noticed I can visit:

https://villaagogo.com/guide/universal-orlando-resort/halloween-horror-nights-2017/ , https://villaagogo.com/guide/universal-orlando-resort/halloween-horror-nights-2017 and also the index.html extension after each slash.

I am not sure how to fix this. I have the following in my config file:

```
permalink: /:categories/:title/
```

and in the  of the template I have the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | absolute_url }}">
```

Do I need to do anything else? The same occurs on the main page of the blog too, with and without the slash /blog/ and /blog

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The canonical is good and should be obeyed, but you should also redirect one to the other with a 301 redirect.

It looks like you're good to go though:

```
curl -I "https://villaagogo.com/guide/universal-orlando-resort/halloween-horror-nights-2017"
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Content-Length: 206
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Location: https://villaagogo.com/guide/universal-orlando-resort/halloween-horror-nights-2017/
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 23:41:18 GMT
```